# HABTM with Pagination

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination, find, has-and-belongs-to-many

At first take a look at the following model structure:

Model *Building*:

```
id
name
```

Model *BuildingRange*:

```
id
building_id
postalcode
```

Ok, so *BuildingRange* $belongsTo *Building* and *Building* $hasMany *BuildingRange*. Should be clear til' here.

Now let

```
$current_postalcode="12345";
```

I know want to do something like this in the *BuildingController*:

```
$this->paginate('Building',array('Building.BuildingRange.postalcode'=>$current_postalcode));
```

In text: I want to select all buildings for that an entry "BuildingRange" with $current_postalcode exists. How do you do that?

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with such a `hasMany` association, CakePHPs auto-magic needs two queries, one on the `Building` table, and one on the `BuildingRange` table. When passing conditions via the `pagiante` method, these conditions will be passed to the first query, and thus this it will fail since the associated models table isn't joined.

This problem can be solved on a few different ways, one would be using an ad-hoc join, for example:

```
$this->paginate = array
(
    'joins' => array
    (
        array
        (
            'table' => 'building_ranges',
            'alias' => 'BuildingRange',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'conditions' => array('BuildingRange.building_id = Building.id')
        )
    )
);
$this->paginate('Building', array('BuildingRange.postalcode' => $current_postalcode));
```

This would result in a query that looks something like this:

```
SELECT `Building`.`id`,
       `Building`.`name`
FROM   `buildings` AS `Building`
       LEFT JOIN `building_ranges` AS `BuildingRange`
              ON ( `BuildingRange`.`building_id` = `Building`.`id` )
WHERE  `BuildingRange`.`postalcode` = '12345'
LIMIT  20
```

Note that in the conditions passed to the `paginate` method there is no need to reference the `BuildingRange` model through the `Building` model, ie no need to use `Builduing.BuildingRange` (that wouldn't work anyway).

ps, it's always good to mention the CakePHP version you are using!

Comment: thanks that ad-hoc solution seems to work like a charm. I would like to mention that - of course - it would also have been possible to use the BuildingRangeController and then everything would work without any additional joins. But I wanted the controller to be `Building`so your solution is perfect.